# In Python, how to define a function wrapper which validates an argument with a certain name?

Tags: python, wrapper, python-decorators

I'm writing several functions which accept an argument called `policy`, which is allowed only to have certain values (namely, `'allow'` or `'deny'`). If it doesn't, I would like a `ValueError` to be raised.

For brevity, I would like to define a decorator for this. So far, I have come up with the following:

```
def validate_policy(function):
    '''Wrapper which ensures that if the function accepts a 'policy' argument, that argument is either 'allow' or 'deny'.'''
    def wrapped_function(policy, *args, **kwargs):
        if policy not in ['allow', 'deny']:
            raise ValueError("The policy must be either 'allow' or 'deny'.")
        return function(policy, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped_function
```

The problem is that this only works if `policy` is the first positional argument of the function. However, I would like to allow for `policy` to appear at any position.

To be specific, here are some (dummy) functions called `make_decision` and `make_informed_decision` which accept an argument `policy` at different positions, and some test cases to go with them:

```
import pytest

@validate_policy
def make_decision(policy):      # The 'policy' might be the first positional argument
    if policy == 'allow':
        print "Allowed."
    elif policy == 'deny':
        print "Denied."

@validate_policy
def make_informed_decision(data, policy):   # It also might be the second one
    if policy == 'allow':
        print "Based on the data {data} it is allowed.".format(data=data)
    elif policy == 'deny':
        print "Based on the data {data} it is denied.".format(data=data)


'''Tests'''
def test_make_decision_with_invalid_policy_as_positional_argument():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        make_decision('foobar')

def test_make_decision_with_invalid_policy_as_keyword_argument():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        make_decision(policy='foobar')

def test_make_informed_decision_with_invalid_policy_as_positional_argument():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        make_informed_decision("allow", "foobar")

def test_make_informed_decision_with_invalid_policy_as_keyword_argument():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        make_informed_decision(data="allow", policy="foobar")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pytest.main([__file__])
```

Currently all the tests pass except the third one, because the first positional argument `'allow'` is interpreted as the `policy` rather than as the `data` as it should be.

How can I adapt the `validate_policy` decorator such that all the tests pass?

Comment: Make policy a required keyword argument. Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: [Rick Teachey](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2437514/rick-teachey), that seems like a good idea, except my code base is in Python 2, so [PEP 3102](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) has not been implemented. I assume that is what you meant by making `policy` a required keyword argument?

Comment: Bummer.........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `inspect` module's [`Signature.bind`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Signature.bind) function:

```
import inspect

def validate_policy(function):
    '''Wrapper which ensures that if the function accepts a 'policy' argument, that argument is either 'allow' or 'deny'.'''
    signature= inspect.signature(function)
    def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs):
        bound_args= signature.bind(*args, **kwargs)
        bound_args.apply_defaults()
        if bound_args.arguments.get('policy') not in ['allow', 'deny']:
            raise ValueError("The policy must be either 'allow' or 'deny'.")
        return function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped_function
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using [inspect.getcallargs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getcallargs):

```
def validate_policy(function):
    '''Wrapper which ensures that if the function accepts a 'policy' argument, that argument is either 'allow' or 'deny'.'''
    def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs):
        call_args = inspect.getcallargs(function, *args, **kwargs)
        if 'policy' in call_args:
            if call_args['policy'] not in ['allow', 'deny']:
                raise ValueError("The policy must be either 'allow' or 'deny'.")
        return function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped_function
```

It makes all the tests pass.